# jQuery!? Как словить resizeStop()?

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, html, javascript

допустим есть функция

```
$(window).resize(function(){
// делай что-то, а потом
if (resize==stop) { alert(1); }
});
```

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Detector,
    onStop = function(){
        console.log('stop!');
    };
$(window).resize(function(){
    clearTimeout(Detector);
    Detector = setTimeout(onStop, 200);
});
```

Работает так: на начале ресайза запускает отсчёт времени, если по истечении 0.2сек ресайза не было запускаем функцию onStop, если ресайз всётаже был - обнуляем таймер и вновь устанавливаем его

Comment: только замени console.log('stop!') если в эксплорере будешь тестить